# Redirect to PayPal checkout before or after order confirmation

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, cart

So I'm making a small shopping cart app.
The checkout project goes like this:
Collect user info -> Order confirmation page where all order data is listed -> User clicks OK and gets redirected to paypal -> User logins to his pp account -> Gets redirected back to my page, his pp account is charged, and is greeted with the message "Thank you for ordering here's your order code: xxx".

OR is this the preferred way:
Collect user info -> Redir to paypal -> User logins to his pp account -> Redirected back to my site, to the order confirmation page which includes all order's info and the message "Your account is not charged yet, pressing confirm will place the order and charge your account" -> User presses confirm, order is saved, charge is made

I think way #1 is better because its less confusing to the buyer, however I've seen some sites (including ebay) that work like way #2.
Which way would you prefer and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do something after "Redirected back to my site", e.g. some validation that may block few customers (say if you have some black list of PayPal accounts), then you want to go with option#2. If you will accept the payment anyway, option#1 is enough. Both options are widely accepted on many online merchants.

If I remember correctly, for option#1, customer will see "Pay" button when he confirm the transaction on PayPal, while for option#2, it will be "continue" since there's no immediate payment.

And for option#2, you have to call PayPal one more time to finish the payment (you may want to do it in back end so you can retry if anything went wrong), this will be an extra work to be trade off when compared with option#1.